# Validación Formato Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, numberformat

En un servicio spring me piden obtener un String del cual tengo que validar el formato con el que llega para poder trasladarlo a otro servicio, en caso de no venir en el formato que me indican mandaría un error.

En este caso piden que el formato siempre sea XXX-XXX (tres números un guion y otros tres números)

Existe alguna forma de validar este formato de campo.

Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, agrega lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta por favor, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Existe, usando el package `javax.validation.constraints`:

Supongamos que tienes un bean o DTO que te llega en un controller:

```
class MiDTO {
    private String dato;
    // ... otros datos y getters y setters
}
```

---

```
@RestController
class Controlador {

    @PostMapping
    public boolean procesaDato(@RequestBody MiDTO dto) {
        // ... hago cosas con el DTO que recibo
    }
}
```

Puedes añadir las anotaciones así:

```
class MiDTO {

    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp = "\\d{3}-\\d{3}")
    private String dato;
    // ... otros datos y getters y setters
}

@RestController
class Controlador {

    @PostMapping
    public boolean procesaDato(@Valid @RequestBody MiDTO dto) {
        // ... hago cosas con el DTO que recibo
    }
}
```

Y ya automáticamente se devuelve un HTTP 400 si no se cumplen las validaciones.
Pero por supuesto esto no es más que un ejemplo sencillo, se puede personalizar el error devuelto, o validar **después** de entrar al método del controlador usando un Validator y luego listar la lista de errores, por ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes validarlo usando este expresión regular [`[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}`](https://regexr.com/5lidq)

```
String str = "123-254";

if (str.matches("[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}")) {
    // matches
} else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("The code is not valid.");
}
```